# validating controls inside different div in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJs. I have 2 div, which I am hiding and showing each other. Each div contains few controls, which I have set "required" validation on click of submit button. By default the div "createMenu" is shown. Below is the code used:

`<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
      <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid &&               add()" novalidate="">
         <div class="container" ng-show="createMenu">

            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-2">
                   <label>Name :</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                   <input type="text" maxlength="150" required="" ng- model="testName" name="testName" />
               </div>
            </div>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.testName.$error.required">Name is required</span>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" />
         </div>
         <div class="container" ng-show="copyView">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <label class="control-label">New Name :</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <input type="text" required="" maxlength="150" class="form-control" ng-model="NewName" name="NewName" />
                  </div>
             </div>
         <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.NewName.$error.required">New Name is required</span>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="copydata()" /> 
    </div>`

The issue is: If I click on the submit button in the first div, the controls in the div "copyView" is also getting validated. When the first submit button is clicked, I want to validate the textbox available in the "createMenu" div only. when the "copyView" div is shown, than at that time, when the submit button inside that div is clicked, the "New Name" textbox should be validated.

How to differentiate between the two divs, when the error messages are shown.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate `form` tag for the separate `div` tag.
like

```
<div ng-controller="name">
 <form>
   //first dive
 </form>
 <form>
   //second div
 </form>
</div>
```